# Strange behaviour with JEditorPane

Tags: java, swing, url, jeditorpane

I've made a custom class that's extending JEditorPane and makes use of it's setPage()-method. However I've encountered a very strange issue while using it. This is how I've implemented it;

```
class WebReader extends JEditorPane {

  WebReader(String addressIn) {
    setEditable(false);
    showPage(addressIn)
  }

  void showPage(String address) {    
    try {
      setPage(address);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

A call could look something like this;

```
WebReader fooReader = new WebReader("https://www.google.com");
fooReader.showPage("https://www.google.comxxxx");
```

Which isn't supposed to work but mysteriously does.

What's very strange is that it doesn't catch a faulty URL if I've already entered a correct one. For example if I've entered "https://www.google.com", which works fine (as it should) and after that enter https://www.google.comxxxxx, it still displays google.com on my JEditorPane and doesn't raise an exception (which I want it to do).

Worth noting is that if I enter https://www.google.comxxxxx as my 'starting URL', it will indeed raise an exception.

EDIT: Added some more code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] .

Comment: What do you want to see? Because the rest is just visual (I've put the JEditorPane inside a ScrollPane with a Listener attached), and I get the 'wrong' indata (address) into my method above. So it's basically just that snippet that I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: You said that you were "extending JEditorPane", please show us the code of your custom implementation.

Comment: My implementation is above. Whenever I want to change the shown page I make a call to my WebReader's showPage()-method.

Comment: So you create a `WebReader` object with a given address, then later call its `showPage` with a different address ? Could you add that part of your code ?

Comment: Exactly. Sure! But it's nothing fancy

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you extending JEditorPane, is WebReader a new type of JEditorPane? Are you overriding any JEditorPane methods? As far as I can tell from your code snippets you have no need of extending JEditorPane and your WebReader class should just have-a JEditorPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it!

I added the following to my showPage():

```
setEditorKit(createDefaultEditorKit());
```

So it creates a new EditorKit for each time the web-page is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You won’t get an IOException if the page is loaded asynchronously (in the background).  Whether a URL is loaded asynchronously depends on the Document installed by the EditorKit for the content type you are loading.  From the [documentation for JEditorPane.setPage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setPage-java.net.URL-):

> This may load either synchronously or asynchronously depending upon the document returned by the `EditorKit`. If the `Document` is of type `AbstractDocument` and has a value returned by `AbstractDocument.getAsynchronousLoadPriority` that is greater than or equal to zero, the page will be loaded on a separate thread using that priority.
>
> If the document is loaded synchronously, it will be filled in with the stream prior to being installed into the editor with a call to `setDocument`, which is bound and will fire a property change event. If an `IOException` is thrown the partially loaded document will be discarded and neither the document or page property change events will be fired. If the document is successfully loaded and installed, a view will be built for it by the UI which will then be scrolled if necessary, and then the page property change event will be fired.
>
> If the document is loaded asynchronously, the document will be installed into the editor immediately using a call to `setDocument` which will fire a document property change event, then a thread will be created which will begin doing the actual loading. In this case, the page property change event will not be fired by the call to this method directly, but rather will be fired when the thread doing the loading has finished. It will also be fired on the event-dispatch thread. Since the calling thread can not throw an `IOException` in the event of failure on the other thread, the page property change event will be fired when the other thread is done whether the load was successful or not.

Obviously in this case, the EditorKit for a web page is an HTMLEditorKit.  From the [documentation of HTMLEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html):

> Larger documents involve a lot of parsing and take some time to load. By default, this kit produces documents that will be loaded asynchronously if loaded using `JEditorPane.setPage`.

A workaround is to load the document synchronously yourself, instead of using JEditorPane.setPage:

```
Document doc;

URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
try (InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream()) {
    String contentType = connection.getContentType();
    EditorKit editorKit =
        JEditorPane.createEditorKitForContentType(contentType);
    doc = editorKit.createDefaultDocument();
    editorKit.read(stream, doc, 0);
}

pane.setDocument(doc);
```

Comment: Exactly what I found as well, great find mate! Thanks alot.